# unable to access elements using XPathNavigator

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am following this post since it is similar to mine:[*](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=40219)
This is how my XML looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Course name="engineering">
<Level4>
    <Module Name="electric" CreditVal="22">
        <Assignment Name="wer" Score="22" Weight="50">
        </Assignment>
        <Assignment Name="asd" Score="50" Weight="50">
        </Assignment>
    </Module>
</Level4>
</Course>
```

My xml can have n times modules and assignments within a level. There are only 3 levels. (Haven't included the other two levels).

This is how I am currently getting the details of the Level modules and assignment:

```
XPathDocument xpd = new XPathDocument("myXMLFile.xml");
        XPathNavigator xmln = xpd.CreateNavigator();



            //getting modules in level 4
            foreach (XPathNavigator mod in xpd.CreateNavigator().Select("/Level4/Module")) {
                //Accessing module elemtns
                if (mod.HasAttributes) {
                Module modtoadd = new Module();
                modtoadd.Name = mod.GetAttribute("Name", "");
                Console.WriteLine(modtoadd.Name);
                modtoadd.CreditValue = int.Parse(mod.GetAttribute("CreditVal", ""));
                Console.WriteLine(modtoadd.CreditValue);
                modtoadd.Assignments = new List<Assignment>();
                //Accessing assignment elements within the module element
                foreach (XPathNavigator asgn in xpd.CreateNavigator().Select("Course/Level4/Module/Assignment"))
                {
                    Assignment asn = new Assignment();
                    asn.Name = asgn.GetAttribute("Name","");
                    Console.WriteLine(asn.Name);
                    asn.Weighting = int.Parse(asgn.GetAttribute("Weight", ""));
                    Console.WriteLine(asn.Weighting);
                    asn.UsersScore = int.Parse(asgn.GetAttribute("Score", ""));
                    Console.WriteLine(asn.UsersScore);
                    modtoadd.Assignments.Add(asn);
                };
                courseXML.Level_41.Add(modtoadd);
            }

        };
```

I am able to write to the file but unable to read it. Upon debugging, I've noticed it checks the foreach conditions but doesn't validate to true hence it doesn't reach any code inside the foreach loop so obviously there is something wrong in my foreach condition but I can see where.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the root node in your expression. `"/Course/Level4/Module"`

Comment: Or start the expression with //

Comment: Thanks it works :) Can't believe I forgot that basic thing. Spent too much time on this :(